# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: mysql, sql

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'AND Sold = 0 ORDER BY Date DESC,Count DESC,Price
> ASC' at line 14 in {path} on line 1026

### Query:

```
select * from (numbers t inner join (select distinct n.Number
from (
  select 1 start union all select 2  union all select 3 union all 
  select 4 union all select 5 
) s cross join numbers n
where 
  left(substring(n.Number, s.start, 2), 1) <> right(substring(n.Number, s.start, 2), 1)
  and
  n.Number like concat(
    '%', substring(n.Number, s.start, 2), 
    substring(n.Number, s.start, 2),
    substring(n.Number, s.start, 2),
    substring(n.Number, s.start, 2), '%'
  )) n on n.Number = t.Number) AND Sold = 0 ORDER BY Date DESC,Count DESC,Price ASC
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Why not check for the SQL syntax on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have a wrong couple of before `numbers t .... and SOLD = 0`

```
select * 
from numbers t 
inner join (select distinct n.Number
  from (
    select 1 start 
    union all select 2  
    union all select 3 
    union all select 4 
    union all select 5 
) s 
cross join numbers n
where 
  left(substring(n.Number, s.start, 2), 1) <> right(substring(n.Number, s.start, 2), 1)
  and
  n.Number like concat(
    '%', substring(n.Number, s.start, 2), 
    substring(n.Number, s.start, 2),
    substring(n.Number, s.start, 2),
    substring(n.Number, s.start, 2), '%'
  )) n on n.Number = t.Number AND Sold = 0 
  ORDER BY Date DESC,Count DESC,Price ASC
```

anyway do the several nested  subquery check if my suggestion is really wht you need

Answer (score 0):

Error is showing near - "AND Sold" so after finishing query you didnt started "where" clause. Add "Where" clause then write your condition